# Angular 5 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME for image from express server

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am having some trouble displaying an image from my node.js (express server) localhost:3000/assets/images/uploads. This works fine when I enter this URL in the browser, the browser display the image but when I assign this to a variable in my Angular 5 app and use binding to the , I get

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

I am attaching the code below. Please review it.

```js
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  user: any;
  url: "";
  path: SafeUrl;
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL, itemAlias: 'photo'});
  
  constructor(private authService: AuthServiceService,
              private userService: UsersService,
              private http: Http,
              private el: ElementRef,
              private _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer) {

      
    
    
    
   }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.authService.user;
    console.log(this.user);
    this.path = this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.user.img);
```

```html
<input type="file" name="photo" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
<!-- button to trigger the file upload when submitted -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
      Upload with ng-2 file uploader
</button>


<div class="user profile">
 <div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui grid">
   <div class="ui five wide column">
    <div class="ui card">
  
      <a class="image poping up" href="" id="profile-avatar" data-content="avatar" data-variation="inverted tiny" data-position="bottom center">
       <img [src] = "path" target="_blank" title="Hamza"/>
      </a>

     <div class="content">
      <span class="header text center">Hamza</span>
      <span class="username text center">Hamza</span>
     </div>
     <div class="extra content">
      <ul class="text black">
     
        <li><i class="octicon octicon-location"></i> Lahore</li>
      
      
        <li>
         <i class="octicon octicon-mail"></i>
         <a href="" rel="nofollow">email</a>
        </li>
       

       <li><i class="octicon octicon-clock"></i> date</li>
 
 

      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="ui eleven wide column">
    <div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
     <a class="activity">
      <i class="octicon octicon-repo"></i> Posts
     </a>
     <a class="item">
      <a class="activity">
       <i class="octicon octicon-rss"></i> Top Posts
      </a>
     </a>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The browser adds `http://` at the beginning for you when entering `localhost:3000/assets/images/uploads` in the address bar. That won't happen in your code. You need to provide a valid URL, with the protocol.

Answer (score 21):

SOLUTION!

For anyone having this issue, please make sure that the address you are providing in the image source attribute is appended with "http://", as in my case I was not appending it.
This solved the problem for me and now it works like a charm!

you're url must be somewhat like this : "http://localhost:3000/assets/images/uploads/c91a3649fc432040e54b9179a72539ad1530343409773.png"

The confusing part actually was that when you write it in the browser's url, without ***http://***, it automatically appends it without letting us know but this isn't the case with Angular, you have to explicitly write it.
Happy Coding.
I hope this helps someone as it took me 14 hours to figure out.